# Spring MongoDB distict - can't get full document

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have collection in following format.

```
{
id:____,
name:"Carlos",
city:"Mumbai"
},
{
id:____,
name:"Pravin",
city:"Mumbai"
},
{
id:_____,
name:"Gaurav",
city:"Ahmedabad"
}
```

I want whole document distinct by city. I tried the db.collection.distinct("city"). But it returns only distinct cities.

Current Output:

```
["Mumbai","Ahmedabad"]
```

Expected Output:

```
{
id:____,
name:"Carlos",
city:"Mumbai"
},
{ 
id:_____,
name:"Gaurav",
city:"Ahmedabad"
}
```

Above you can see there is only one record of "Mumbai". I need this kind of output.

Anyone know how we can get whole document with distinct in spring-mongodb?

Comment: Can you be a bit specific, with the above sample documents, what is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for updating, just one more question; suppose there are many duplicate cities, what is the criteria for choosing the name e.g. in your sample above you chose `name: "Carlos"`, why not `name: "Pravin"`?

Comment: If there are two document with the same cities,  any one document we need to select. I can be first or last. No criteria for that. I just need only one document of city "Mumbai"

Comment: Currently I have done it using Set in Java. But it is very slow in performance. So I have to do that with mongo query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try running an aggregation pipeline operation where you can include the the other fields inside the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator. Two examples that show this approach follow:

---

**Mongo Shell:**

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$city",
            "id": { "$first": "$_id" },
            "name": { "$first": "$name" }
        }
    }
]

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

---

**Spring Data MongoDB:**

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = repository.getMongoTemplate();
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    group("city")
        .first("_id").as("id")
        .first("name").as("name")
);

AggregationResults<OutputType> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,
                                            "collection", OutputType.class);
List<OutputType> mappedResult = result.getMappedResults();
```

---